# Math.Round() is not working on Windows Phone. Why?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I was trying to Round Off the Value using `Math.Round()` . But its not working. May i know why ? Anyone here knows exact reason ?

```
        double num = 0;
        if (double.TryParse(number.Text, out num) && num > 0 && num < 60)
        {
            Math.Round(num);
            browser.Navigate(new Uri("/file" + num + ".html", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Expected Input Range: 1 to 59");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.Round` returns the rounded value, so you will have to assign the new value back to `num`

Example:

```
double num = 0;
if (double.TryParse(number.Text, out num) && num > 0 && num < 60)
{
    num = Math.Round(num);
    browser.Navigate(new Uri("/file" + num + ".html", UriKind.Relative));
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Expected Input Range: 1 to 59");
}
```

But I have a feeling you dont want any decimal places in that case you cab just cast as `int`

```
 browser.Navigate(new Uri("/file" + (int)num + ".html", UriKind.Relative));
```

Tests:

```
double num = 34.5;
num = Math.Round(num); // returns 34.0

double num = 34.5;
int newNum = (int)num; // returns 34
```

Comment: i was getting input from user